# Core Data: Fetch

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a 5 screens.  Each screen has options the user choses i.e. via Time & Date picker, and some UIFields that the user will type in.  So I created ONE Entity and added all the attributes (25).  I created a NSObjectSubClass called LM

In each scene I'm doing the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LM *lMData;

NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
            DateLabel.text = date;
            self.lMData.dateLabel = date;

self.lmData.nameField5 = UITextFieldName5.text;
```

Before the User Segue's to the next screen, I have:

```
NSError *error;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

 if (![context save:&error])
      {
           NSLog(@"There was an error in Save:%@",error);
      }
```

Now to fetch, all I want to do is show the data in a UITableViewController that is custom.  That has 12 Sections and will show 2 cells in each section.  I don't really need sorting.  I just want the cells to show up in the right sections.

To fetch, I have the following method:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchResultsController
{
    if (_fetchResultsController !=nil)
{
    return _fetchResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LM"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTimeLabel" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

_fetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

return _fetchResultsController;
```

}

From what I read, it appears that in order for me to fetch I have to sort, hence, the following line:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTimeLabel"
```

There is an attribute called "startTimeLabel" in my entity.  But I have it in there because I'm being forced to sort.  However, I really don't need to sort.

Now to display, which is not displaying anything at this point:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

  return [[self.fetchResultsController sections] count];   //I need 10 sections here;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = [[self.fetchResultsController   sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [secInfo numberOfObjects]; //I need 2 rows in each section here
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    LM *letsMeetData = [self.fetchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = letsMeetData.dateLabel;

    return cell;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is my code to save and fetch correct?
2. What can I do to get rid of the Sort?  I don't need to Sort.
3. I know my code to display the fetched data in the UITableView is wrong.  Please advise.
4. Last, I also need to save each of these forms as objects so the user can later pull them up later.  Do I need to create another Entity to store LM objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey to work with coredata you need to create an Entity class from NSManagedObject.

(1)You can save and retrieve the data using the entity class.

```
LM_Entity *lm = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LM_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
//Your code
lm.nameField5 = UITextFieldName5.text;
//Now save
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

While retrieving use

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LM_Entity"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

(2)You **need** to specify a sort descriptor while working with **NSFetchedResultsController**.

(3)Your code is correct for displaying the fetched data

(4) Yes you need to create an Entity class to save and retrieve the data.(see 1).

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) for more information about coredata.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Do I have to do [self.managedObjectContext save:&error]; after every UITextField?  If one Scene has 5 UITextfields, can I do it just once?

Comment: yes you must first assign all UITextField values to LM_Entity's variables and finally you can call [self.managedObjectContext save:&error]; **once**.